# How do you check if Net Framework Developer Pack v4.6 and v4.0 is installed on the server?

Tags: windows, microsoft, net

How do you check if Net Framework Developer Pack v4.6 and v4.0 is installed on the server? I have a Github action telling me to install these, and IT tells me both are installed. How do you check that? Is there a command line script I can run to see if they're installed?

Answer (score 1):

### Detect .NET Framework 1.0 through 4.0

> Each version of .NET Framework from 1.1 to 4.0 is listed as a subkey at **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP`**

### Detect .NET Framework 4.5 and later versions

> The version of .NET Framework (4.5 and later) installed on a machine is listed in the registry at **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`**

You can use this article for more information

[How to: Determine which .NET Framework versions are installed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)